# how can I do, if user logined, he can change only his profile nodejs/mongodb/mongoose/pug

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, passport.js

So basically I have a dynamic route that routes to every user username in DB

```
router.get('/:username', function (req, res) {
  User.findOne({username:decodeURI(req.params.username)}, function (err, user) {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (user == null) {

    }else if(user !== null){
      res.render('user-profile', {
        user:user
      });
    }
  });
});
```

And I want to check for example: if the user that logged in is "alpha", and he seeing his profile on this URL: http://localhost:8080/users/alpha, then display him private information so only he can see it.
And if "beta" wanna see "alpha" profile, he doesn't see any private information of alpha

I'm working with passport, passport-local and express session

Comment: you can have isAuthenticated state in ur reducer  and also match the userid key  if you visit someone profile, based on that you can distinguish, what do you think?

Comment: I think its good but how can I do that? @Raju

Comment: you can have userid in the url , and your logged in user's userid in the reducer , so you can compare that  along with isAuthenticated state

Comment: thanks that worked! @Raju

Comment: glad to help :) but to be honest we shouldn't expose userid like that in url, maybe you can use username, username must be unique then in your whole database,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not as Complicated as you think . So, Lets discuss the scenario There are two users A and B . What we want to achieve here is that the url /users/:username only displays the public information of the user and if username is same as that of the logged-in user in that case it would also display the private information of the logged in User

A very simple approach would be to list all the information (public and private) but only display the private information on the profile page if the id or username for /users/:username is same as the logged in user.(can easily be acheived through any template engine)

if you are using passport then the logged in users info gets attached to the req object that you could use to simply check whether you need to display the information or not.